# Random Token Not Matching Session when form is sent

Tags: php, forms, oop, session

Im building a login form which I am trying to make as hackable as possible, I am using a 3 strike rule which suspends login for 3 minutes when entered wrong 3 times to prevent brute force entry and its using sha256 which as far as I know is not hackable to date, with using random salt and pepper technique.

The password is then split randomly and put back together again

Anyway enough of that :)

I have built a form which sends a hidden form field with the random session token which changes each and every time the form is generated, if that token does not match the current session on the users browser it reject the form.

The problem is that for some reason when sending the form it then does not match even though it should.

I have no idea why...

Here is my code:

Creating the session:

```
$formsession = $session->setSessions('RANDOM_FORM_SESSION,' . $general->randomString());
```

From session class I have done:

```
public function setSessions($key = ''){

    if(is_array($key)){

        foreach($key as $k){

            list($sessionname, $result) = explode(',', $k);
            $_SESSION[$sessionname] = $result;

        }

    } else {

        list($sessionname, $result) = explode(',', $key);
        $_SESSION[$sessionname] = $result;

    }

}
```

From the form class I have created:

```
public function createHiddenPosts($value, $name, $id = ''){

    if(!empty($id)){ $id = 'id="'.$id.'" '; }

    return '<input type="hidden" value="'.$value.'" '.$id.'name="'.$name.'">';

}
```

From the frontend:

```
echo $login->createHiddenPosts($_SESSION['RANDOM_FORM_SESSION'], 'formissent');
```

Finally the code which checks that the session is equal to the token:

```
if(!$errors){ if(isset($_POST['formissent']) && $_POST['formissent'] == $_SESSION['RANDOM_FORM_SESSION']){ $form = true; } else { $errors[] = 'Our site only accepts forms submitted from our website and only from users who accept cookies!'; } }
```

For the life of me I can not see why its not matching. Any light would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: just because you are changing the session before checking for post. Just move your `$formsession = $session->set....` to after the `if(isset($_POST[....`

Comment: @bansi does this mean that the page actually refreshes before sending form?

Comment: @bansi by setting the session from when the form is submitted would mean the token is not generated which would come back failed anyway

Comment: I may be wrong, but as far as i understand you are creating a form with hidden `formissent`, so far good. When you submit your form your code hits `$formsession = $session->set...` and this new value is stored to `$_SESSION['RANDOM_FORM_SESSION']`. Then later in the code when you compare `$_POST['formissent'] == $_SESSION['RANDOM_FORM_SESSION']` it won't match because `$_SESSION['RANDOM_FORM_SESSION']` is changed with new value. Can only confirm this with more code.

Comment: @bansi thank you, you was correct I set the session after the form is sent check, please put this as an answer and I will accept it :)